# Does this action violate GDPR

Tags: gdpr

If a company is aware that a customer cannot provide a receipt, yet still requests their personal information to facilitate a product exchange due to a defective item, but later denies the exchange based on the lack of a receipt, does this action violate GDPR? Personal information is not required to use the product or services.

Answer (score 2):

No, not based on the facts in question.

The company can reasonably take the personal information in order to locate any record of sale they might have, in the absence of a receipt. This is a valid and logical reason for which a customer may *consent* to the processing of their information. Consent is a valid GDPR ground for the processing of this personal information.

Consent must be informed etcetera, but nothing in the question points to any sort of GDPR problem.

Comment: the data is also justified as *strictly necessary* to perform the requested operation of trying to identify a reciept.