# Will this be considered proof of purchase?

Tags: software, evidence, ownership, sale-of-goods

Each product has a traceable serial number, and to operate the product, it must be registered and activated through the manufacturer's software. The registration and activation process requires the validated serial number. The product is designed to be exclusively compatible with the manufacturer's software, which the manufacturer can remotely control the activation and deactivation, and review the usage log. Unauthorized third party sales, third-party repairs and software are strictly prohibited and inhibited. Transferring of ownership will require the manufacturer's approval too.

To simply put, the product is rendered unusable without the manufacturer's software. The product cannot be repaired, resold or used without the manufacturer's explicit approval.

With this ecosystem, without a receipt, is registering and using the product itself considered proof of purchase?

*Please assist to edit/add the right tags*

Comment: Considering that you're asking about GDPR earlier, the tag you are (again) not adding is the jurisdiction. "Unauthorized third-party sales"? The EU would want to have a word.

Comment: @MSalters right, no resale is allowed. The product will be inoperable if there is a change of ownership(registration). The product is designed and manufactured to be unrepairable and centrally controlled. EU or not, I am appalled by the condition of this ecosystem.

Comment: The EU is cracking down on non-repairable items, but that will still take a while. The resale prohibition could land this company in court today, though. You just need standing (i.e. economic loss because you own a device you can't sell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask whether the facts you describe would be considered "proof of purchase." This entirely depends who you are trying convince that you purchased the thing and what the evidence for the contrary position is.

If everything you say is true, it seems at least to be *evidence* of purchase, which would of course have to be evaluated in the context of any contradictory evidence. If you were to introduce these facts in court as evidence that you purchased a thing, you would need to introduce them via affidavit or oral testimony. You may even need expert opinion evidence or evidence directly from the provider to help establish that there is no other way to have activated the product.

Answer (score 3):

### No

If I steal the item and register it, I haven’t purchased it.

Or, if I collude with the store clerk to steal the item and get an activation code, I haven’t purchased it.

Or, if you buy it and give it to me, I haven’t purchased it.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149246/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-will-this-be-considered-proof-of-purchase); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

### Not as explained

For whom a serial number is proof of purchase depends on their access and data handling.

Let me give you an example:

I just sent in a computer for repair. It has a serial that is unique combined with the manufacturer's name. This serial was also marked on the initial bill of sale by a third-party vendor, denoting it as an individual item. The seller has a database of sales (combined with the customer number and identification of model) and could locate a copy of that bill of sale matching the serial number and then could provide a facsimile for warranty purposes. The manufacturer required the date of sale for warranty purposes, even though they could estimate the sale to have happened between the making and the registration.

To **that** specific vendor, the serial number, combined with proof of who you are, would be enough proof to show that you purchased the product. However, not all stores store specific serial numbers for all products, if they are available at all. For example, the same store also sells flash drives without serial numbers, and they can not be identified but for their type description.

On the other hand, the registration would not help on its own: while the registration allows to narrow down the date of sale and might help to identify the bill at the vendor, it doesn't prove anything that is not on the registration form. If the registration form does not require showing a receipt, it can not prove a sale but only that it was registered on a certain date by a specific person or group.

The manufacturer might identify their wholesaler via the serial number, who in turn might identify the individual store that got the item, and *that* store might then identify the sale if they have sufficient information. But on its own, the registration at best narrows down the time of sale, unless some paperwork of the sale was attached to the registration.

Comment: in other words, the serial number can be used as proof of purchase to both vendor and manufacturer. The only issue is it will require more effort to trace and validate it compared to simply providing a receipt.

Comment: @skies, in the absence of a receipt, what sort of traceability do you presume there to be if the retailer does not retain personal information about the buyer?

Comment: @MichaelHall In the context described in the OP, considering that the manufacturer has complete product visibility and full control throughout the entire supply chain, should a receipt be the sole acceptable proof of purchase?

Comment: @Skies no. **only** if the manufacturer is supplied with a sales receipt **from someone**, they can actually see it. They can *infer* a rough sale date, but they can not access the seller's database, and can't magic numbers into existence that are not saved.

Comment: @Skies,  "*the manufacturer has complete product visibility and full control throughout the entire supply chain*"  Does this mean that they retain the personal information of the retail purchaser?  Because if so, I agree that a paper receipt ought not be required.  But if not, how is the manufacturer to know that the person presenting themselves as the owner made a legitimate qualifying purchase?

Comment: @MichaelHall As mentioned in the OP, to operate the product, it requires registration and activation via the manufacturer's software. Identifiable information for both machine and the owner is required during these steps. If the machine is reported stolen, it will be deactivated promptly. Or if it is a stolen machine, the registration and activation will not be successful.

Comment: @Skies **unless** the registration requires a receipt, the registration does not prove anything besides that somebody registred the machine to their name.

Comment: @Trish You emphasized the known and common way of proofing a purchase but is it necessary in the context described in the OP. If a receipt is required as a proof of purchase, shouldn't it be integrated in the registration process too?

Comment: @Skies should be done for best service and need to be done under law are two vastly different things - it is lot legally required.

Comment: "*If a receipt is required as a proof of purchase, shouldn't it be integrated in the registration process too?*"  Is it not?  This is exactly where I was going with my line of questions - i.e. if proof of purchase is required to register the product, once the product is registered that process should usurp the need to retain a paper receipt, right?  That seems to be what you are asking, are you dealing with a company that refuses to acknowledge such a fact and are looking to see if there is a law addressing the situation?